# php variable together with javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

I have this piece of JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var counter = 0;
            function myFunction() {
                counter++;
                document.getElementById('countervalue').innerHTML = counter;
            }
</script>
```

Which plusses a number with 1 everytime a button is pressed.

The variable "counter" decides what number to start with when the page is loaded.
This number is currently 0. But it is supposed to be a number from the database. So I made a database connection using PHP and I now have the database number in a PHP variable. However, how do I implement it on the JS script? I have tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var counter = $clicks;
                function myFunction() {
                    counter++;
                    document.getElementById('countervalue').innerHTML = counter;
                }
```

The variable $clicks is the number from my database that is supposed to be the starting number when clicking the button.
I tried this as well, with no luck:

```
var counter = <?php $clicks ?>;
```

Comment: var counter = <?php echo $clicks ?>; should do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're close. You're just forgetting to echo your variable's content:

```
var counter = <?php $clicks ?>;
```

should be:

```
var counter = <?php echo $clicks ?>;
```

or, if you have short tags enabled:

```
var counter = <?= $clicks ?>;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var counter = <?=$clicks?>;
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember the `echo`.

```
var counter = <?php echo $clicks; ?>;
function myFunction() {
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('countervalue').innerHTML = counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var counter = <?php echo $clicks; ?>;`

Answer (score 0):

Counter value should be assigned as

```
var counter = <?php echo $clicks ?>;
```